# How to correctly utilize seasonal dummies

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

Suppose I am fitting a model with Arima errors. If there are no seasonal effects the model might be :  $Y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_t + \epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon$ is an Arima process

Say the data is quarterly, and there are seasonal effects I want to model. Let $SD_{i,t}$ be a seasonal dummy indicator variable that is $1$ in season $i$ for $i \in \left\{1, 2, 3, 4\right\}$.

Let $\beta_i, \gamma_i, i\in\left\{1, 2, 3, 4\right\}$ be paramaters for the intercept and regressor.

Is this a correct way to model seasonal effects with regressors? :
$Y_t = \sum_{i = 1} ^ 3 \beta_i SD_{i, t} + \sum_{i = 1} ^ 4 \gamma_i SD_{i, t} X_t + \epsilon_t $

I think I have to have $3$ intercepts instead of $4$ to elliminate redundancy. Can someone please tell me if this is the correct way to utilize seasonal dummies between a dependent and co-seasonal independent regressor?

Also, do I need 3 intercepts? Can I use only 1? Such as : 
$Y_t = \beta_0 + \sum_{i = 1} ^ 4 SD_i \gamma_i X_t + \epsilon$

Or, if I include a time component : 
$Y_t = \beta_0 + \sum_{i = 1} ^ 4 SD_i \gamma_i X_t + f(t) + \epsilon$